# Calling a constructor from another - this keyword usage

Tags: java, constructor, this

Q. Identify the valid option which is used to invoke the no argument constructor, Product(), at Line 1.

```
class Product{
   int productId;
   String productName;

   Product( )   {
         productId=0; productName="";
  } 

   Product(int id, String name)   {
        //access Product() ---- Line 1
        productId=id;
        productName=name;
   } 
}
```

A. this();

Can you help me understand how 'this' reference variable can be used here?

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html) especially the second part related to using `this` with constructors.

Comment: Thanks, I do understand explicit constructor invocation. I'm confused how this() can be used when there's no previous mention of it in the no argument constructor. How does this() know which object it's referring to?

Comment: Incidentally, calling `this()` from `Product(int,String)` is the wrong way to do it: call `this(int,String)` from `Product()` is better, because it is effectively just providing default values for the parameters, and allows you to make those fields final. (Not, of course, that a default id and name actually make any sense anyway - the no-arg ctor should be removed).

Answer (score 1):

> Can you help me understand how 'this' reference variable can be used here?

`this()` isn't using a variable.

It's a special syntactic construct which says "invoke another constructor in the same class". It's called an "explicit constructor invocation" (or, more specifically, an "*alternate constructor invocation*"), and can only appear as the first statement in the constructor (see [language spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7)).

However, you can use `this` as a "variable" later in the constructor, in order to access member variables or instance methods on the instance which is currently being constructed, for instance:

```
this.productId = id;
```